# MKAnnotation not updating position

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am using the `HGMovingAnnotation` and `HGMovingAnnotationView` code off of github to animate a `MKAnnotation` on an `MKmap`.  When I run the example project from HG project everything works fine.

I have altred the original HG project to allow me to manually push a new coordinate to the `HGMapPath` and then move the annotation where I want it.

I have placed a button, for testing, to run the manual process and everything works fine. The annotation moves around the screen. The issue is, when I try to now call this manual method with data from a live socket.io connection, the map annotation won't move.

Also, when the map first loads the annotation won't show up until I move the map a little bit. The same thing for the moving annotation manually, it won't show the movement from the stream of data, until I zoom the map. But if I do the push button way, avoiding the io stream, the annotation moves without needing to zoom or pan the map?

PLACING THE VIEW ANNOTATIONS

```
if(doubleLat && doubleLng) {

            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(doubleLat, doubleLng);

            //Create path object
            self.assignedAmbPath = [[HGMapPath alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate];

            HGMovingAnnotation *movingObject = [[HGMovingAnnotation alloc] initWithMapPath:self.assignedAmbPath];

            self.movingAssignedAmbObject = movingObject;


            // add the annotation to the map
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:movingObject];


            // zoom the map around the moving object
            MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(MKCoordinateForMapPoint(self.movingAssignedAmbObject.currentLocation), span);
            [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

            // start moving the object
            [movingObject start];

        }
```

CODE THAT WORKS

```
 - (IBAction)testMoveBtnPressed:(id)sender {
//TODO: move x and y
DLog(@"============== Test move button was pressed ================ ");
NSLog(@"");

int randn = (random() % 15)+15;
float pscale = (float)randn / 10000;

double lat = 39.9813855 + pscale;
double lng = -75.1502155 + pscale;

for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations){
    MKAnnotationView* anView = [self.mapView viewForAnnotation: annotation];
    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[PhoneAnnotation class]]){
        // Process annotation view
        [((HGMovingAnnotation *)annotation) trackToNewPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)];
    }
  }
}
```

CODE THAT DOESN'T WORK

```
{

                    //TODO: move thing to new location
                    double doubleLat = [lat doubleValue];
                    double doubleLng = [lng doubleValue];
 //                        NSLog(@"--------------- Jason it is -------------  Latitude   being passed in is %f", doubleLat);
//                        NSLog(@"--------------- Jason it is -------------  Longitude being passed in is %f", doubleLng);
//                        
//                        [self.movingAssignedAmbObject trackToNewPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(doubleLat, doubleLng)];




                    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations){
                        MKAnnotationView* anView = [self.mapView viewForAnnotation: annotation];
                        if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[PhoneAnnotation class]]){
                            // Process annotation view
                            [((HGMovingAnnotation *)annotation) trackToNewPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(doubleLat, doubleLng)];

                        }
                    }


                }
```

Comment: Can you post your code?  We won't be able to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the HG library though works as described doesn't work proper, unless your using the path, if you don't create the annotation with a coordinate attached, which it doesn't.